# Firebase Auth Display Name

Tags: javascript

How do I make a firebase login system with email,password and display name? If anyone has a different method please comment what is it.

```js
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
             let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
             changeRequest.displayName = document.getElementById("name")
            
             changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion()
               alert("changed")
```

That is my code for now (for changing their display name) but i keep getting an error: "FIRAuth is not defined."

Comment: means you're not importing the thing that populates FIRAuth.  You probably need to grab the auth library.  If you already have it installed, you can try using the root firebase obj "firebase.auth()?.currentUser..."

Comment: As intriguing as "firebae" sounds, I've fixed the title.

Comment: can you show your imports and how you got "FIRauth" ?

Comment: @Kyle user.profileChangeRequest is not a function. New error

Comment: @AlexanderHemming I don't have imports

Comment: you need to import firebase to use it. It does not come with baseline javascript

Comment: @AlexanderHemming I did it with <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

Comment: @ViktorKnezevic - no you're good now.  You have the root firebase library since you've got the next error - 'let user = firebase.auth()?.currentUser' - that's saying if someone is logged in, set them to that 'user' variable.  I'm guessing they are not logged in, or you are calling it early.

Comment: @Kyle I'm logged in and also it appears in the second I join the website...

Comment: sweet, so that means it should just be that you have the word "firebase"

where is FIrauth coming from? did you make this variable if not it does not exist.

Comment: basically, just need to see where it says "let FIRAuth = etcetcetc"

Comment: @AlexanderHemming idiot I fixed that but i'm getting another error: "util.ts:556 Uncaught TypeError: useren.profileChangeRequest is not a function"

Comment: hey man, i didn't know you fixed it. the language is not necessary when you are having a typeerror error, which is the most basic form of error. "profileChangeRequest " is not a function means that treating it like a function makes no sense. like const string = "hello" then going hello(); but no one can help if you don't actually show where the problem is

Comment: if you dont know how to set break points and eventlisteners in chromedevtools then you may need to learn the basics of programming again.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it looks like you have 2 issues - 1 not setting some FIRAuth variable and then not catching the auth at the right time.

To fix problem 1 you can always just use the root library:

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
```

to

```
let user = firebase.auth()?.currentUser
```

If this is in it's own function, like on a click or something, then wrap everything in an if check:

```
if(user){
     let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
     changeRequest.displayName = document.getElementById("name")

     changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion()
       alert("changed")
}
```

If you need this to kick off as soon as they are logged in then make the auth handling reactionary:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
    if(user){
         let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
         changeRequest.displayName = document.getElementById("name")
        
         changeRequest.commitChangesWithCompletion()
           alert("changed")
    }
});
```

Comment: My error is useren.profileChangeRequest is not a function!

Comment: is it becasue it's "user" and not "useren"

Comment: Nah just my other code:

```js
firebase.database().ref("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        var html = ""
        var some = document.getElementById("something").value
        let useren = firebase.auth()?.currentUser
        let changeRequesten = useren.profileChangeRequest()
        let displayName = changeRequest.displayName```

Comment: same thing - I'd wrap it in a if(useren){  then call stuff on useren - it might just be calling that function before the auth has happened resulting in useren to be null, which means you can't call stuff on it, like .profileChangeRequest()}